# How does \\ suppress spurious spaces while \par\noindent doesn't

Tags: spacing, indentation, paragraphs

I'm trying to build a description-list-with-header-line by using a macro. In the non-MWE, the macro adds additional value like index entries and margin notes, but here I have the simplest case possible.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\pni}[1]{\item{#1} The name of the rose\par\noindent}
\newcommand{\dbs}[1]{\item{#1} The name of the rose\\}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\dbs{abc def}
A book that isn't about roses.

Another paragraph
\pni{abc def}
A book that isn't about roses, either.

Another paragraph
\pni{abc def}%
A book that isn't about roses, either.

Another paragraph\end{description}
\end{document}
```

The first line of the description item consists of a key and title; the rest is descriptive text in paragraphs.

Now, it seems to me to be semantically better to use `\par\noindent` to get ready for the first paragraph of text, because this will obey 'other definitions' of paragraph-ness, as opposed to `\\`, which is simply a line break. But as you can see, `\par\noindent` introduces a spurious space at the start of the new paragraph.

[image]

I know I can suppress this by adding a `%` to my call, but I'd prefer to do this inside the macro. How?

---

In the light of the answers so far (with thanks and apologies to @DavidCarlisle and @egreg), here's a second MWE that more accurately reflects my case. I'm using `enumitem` with `memoir`, which I now see makes my original MWE a bit oversimplified. Here goes:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mfields}{description}{1}
\setlist[mfields]{%
    font=\bfseries\scshape,leftmargin=!,labelwidth=3.5em,
    labelsep=0.5em,itemindent=0pt,listparindent=\parindent}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\mfield}{m m}{%
    \item[#1]#2\par}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\xfield}{m m}{%
    \item[#1]#2\par\noindent\ignorespaces}
\begin{document}
\begin{mfields}
\mfield{abcdef}{The Name of The Rose}
A book that isn't about roses.

Another paragraph goes here etc.

\xfield{ghijkl}{The Island of the Day Before}
A book that isn't about roses, either.

Another paragraph goes here etc.

\xfield{mnopqr}{The Island of the Day Before}

A book that isn't about roses, either.

Another paragraph goes here etc.
\end{mfields}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a primitive feature of TeX's line breaking algorithm that glue (including glue from white space) is discarded at the beginning of the line.  But `\noindent` starts the paragraph already so the following space token produces glue that is not discarded (as it doesn't follow a linebreak.

It would seem that you `The name of the rose` should be part of the list label (optional argument to `\item`) rather than forcing a break after it.

---

As noted in comments, `\par\noindent` has the bad effect of generating a spurious empty paragraph if a blank line follows the command, and  `\par\noindent\ignorespaces` doesn't fix that. However in this context you have 0pt indentation anyway so a simpler definition is

```
\newcommand{\pni}[1]{\item{#1} The name of the rose\par}
```

space tokens and blank likes will be ignored after the `\par` and the paragraph will start with 0 width indentation.

Or if `\listparindent` isn't 0

```
\newcommand{\pni}[1]{\item{#1} The name of the rose\par\bgroup\parindent\z@\everypar{\egroup}}
```

Comment: Thanks, David, that's an interesting idea, but I think I'll go with @egreg's for now. The 'real-life' case is much more complex

Comment: @Brent.Longborough the main disadvantage of using `\par\noindent` and why LaTeX never uses that when suppressing indentation in lists or after a section head is that it means that your text has to come immediately after your command. If you put a blank line before `A book that` then the `\par\noindent` will cause a spurious all white paragraph then you will get a paragraph and indented text. If you used the list code or `\@afterheading` then a blank line could be safely used in this context, just as it can after a `\subsection` or `\item[...]`

Comment: Aha! OK, I'll research 'how lists work' and report back. I appreciate the 'empty paragraph' problem. But I may still have to go with q&d for now...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough I updated answer with a suggestion to address the empty paragraphs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but in my more complex case, that doesn't work, as `\listparindent` isn't zero, so the first para is indented. ing everyone's effort so far...

Comment: @Brent.Longborough Grrr updated again then:-)

Comment: Terribly sorry, but well fixed!. Hence the green tick :)

Answer (score 13):

Whenever you use `\noindent` (or `\indent`) at the end of a macro with arguments, it's good rule to add `\ignorespaces`: the space you see is due to the end of line after `\pni{abc def}`.

So

```
\newcommand{\pni}[1]{\item{#1} The name of the rose\par\noindent\ignorespaces}
```

is the answer.

Why doesn't it happen with `\\`? Because this macro has a `*` variant (and an optional argument, which whould sufficient by itself) and the look up for the `*` eats spaces. In this case it wouldn't make a difference anyway, because the space is at the start of a line.

---

Regarding the new example, if what you want is that the two `\xfield` items give the same result, that is, in the second one the blank line is ignored, you can define a `\ignorespacesandpars` command to be used in place of `\ignorespaces`.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\ignorespacesandpars}{%
  \@ifnextchar\par{\@ignorespacesandpars}{}}
\long\def\@ignorespacesandpars#1{\noindent\ignorespacesandpars}
\makeatother
```

Spaces are eaten up by `\@ifnextchar`, while `\par` token will case the macro to call again itself after having get rid of `\par`.

Comment: 'tis true that `\\ ` eats the space tokens because it looks for `[` but even if you stop it doing that eg use `{\\}` the white space still does not get into the output as glue is discarded, so I think we're both right:-)