# Marginfigure image in tufte-handout is off center when using vertical alignment option

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tufte, includegraphics

When using the `\includgraphics` command (under the `graphicx` package) in the `marginfigure` environment, the image is slightly off center to the right, but only when using the vertical alignment option.

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\geometry{showframe}
  
\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}[-0.5in]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{bb_navy.jpg}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without the vertical alignment, the image is centered as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment defined by `tufte-handout` for inserting figures and other floats in the margin should be fixed by adding a
`\ignorespaces` after `\noindent`.

See
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102026/161015

> It's a primitive feature of TeX's line breaking algorithm that glue
> (including glue from white space) is discarded at the beginning of the
> line. But `\noindent` starts the paragraph already so the following
> space token produces glue that is not discarded,(as it doesn't follow a linebreak).

And https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102025/161015

> Whenever you use `\noindent` (or `\indent`) at the end of a macro with
> arguments, it's good rule to add `\ignorespaces`

[image: z]

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\geometry{showframe}

\makeatletter

\renewenvironment{@tufte@margin@float}[2][1.2ex]%
{\FloatBarrier% process all floats before this point so the figure/table numbers stay in order.
    \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}%
        \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}%  
            \@tufte@caption@font%
            \def\@captype{#2}%  
            \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%        
            \@tufte@caption@justification%
            \@tufte@margin@par%         
            \setlength{\parindent}{0.0pc}%
            \noindent%
            \ignorespaces%  added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<       
        }
        {%
        \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
        \marginpar{\usebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
\begin{marginfigure}[-0.5in]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{marginfigure}

    
\begin{marginfigure}% [-0.5in]
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{marginfigure}  
        
\end{document
```

Comment: +1 Great, you found the culprit **and** an explanation!

Comment: Yes, this is the "fix." Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can fix that by moving the `\noindent` directly to the beginning of the minipage:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-handout}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\geometry{showframe}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{@tufte@margin@float}[2][-1.2ex]%
  {\FloatBarrier% process all floats before this point so the figure/table numbers stay in order.
  \begin{lrbox}{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}%
  \begin{minipage}{\marginparwidth}%
    \noindent% <-- MOVE HERE
    \@tufte@caption@font%
    \def\@captype{#2}%
    \hbox{}\vspace*{#1}%
    \@tufte@caption@justification%
    \@tufte@margin@par%
  }
  {\end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
  \marginpar{\usebox{\@tufte@margin@floatbox}}%
  }
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{marginfigure}[-.5in]
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]